# how to extend konakart type system

Tags: konakart

I am starting a konakart e-commerce project and have little knowledge about it. 
I plan on developing a separate web application that will communicate with konakart using the "java api" approach. 
The biggest problem I have now it that I can't figure out how to go about extending konakart type system.

Lets assume I plan on selling vacations on my e-commerce site, 
I am interested in finding out best approaches for the following questions:
1) I want to create a new entities (for example a Hotel entity)
2) I want to create relationships between konakarts existing types and my new types (for instance a relationship between hotel and product(the vacation))
3) I want to know how to extend konakarts existing types with new fields (for instance extend the promotion type with a new filed "stars" - eg: there will be 10% of for vacations in 5 star hotels)

I could create my custom objects store them in a separate DB and do all the merging & saving logic myself 
but I am wondering if there is some support in konakart for this kind of requirements (for instance similat to hybris type system).

Answer (score 0):

There  a  couple  of  FUNDAMENTAL   faults  in   this  question.

That's  why  you   didn't   get  any  response.

title  of  this  question - should  be  "Extension"  and  not  "Type  System".

For  integration,   JAVA  API  figures  rather lower in the other alternatives...

REST.
SOAP.
SPRING.
CSV (IMPEX) - Quite  A  Low Level  mechanism  which  Maps  Almost  Directly  to  Data Model. 
No  Higher Level Abstraction Is Required.

Version 4 of the hybris-platform  - Out  -Of -The- Box  Platformwebservices extension.

JMS  EXTENSION.